# Create a list item using Sharepoint REST API and HTML

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, html

I'm working on SharePoint Server 2016. I have a modal with some input fields and a Submit Button. And I used jQuery to extract text from input fields in Modal. When I click on Submit, nothing is happening and unable to add modal input data in the list.

But if I give data in rest API code, then it is working. I can't figure it what's my mistake in the code and method done in rest API or HTML. Please help me to resolve this issue. Below is my code snippet:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-item form-item-pid form-type-textfield form-group">

 <label class="control-label" for="edit-pname">Project Name<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
 <input class="form-control form-text" type="text" id="edit-pname" name="pname" value="" size="60" minlength="3" maxlength="128" required>

</div>
   
<div class="form-item form-item-pid form-type-textfield form-group">

 <label class="control-label" for="edit-pmanager">Project Manager<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
 <input class="form-control form-text" type="text" id="edit-pmanager" name="pmanager" value="" size="60" minlength="3" maxlength="128" required>
                                    
</div>
                                    
<div class="form-item form-item-pid form-type-textfield form-group">

 <label class="control-label" for="edit-aname">Account Name<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
 <input class="form-control form-text" type="text" id="edit-aname" name="aname" value="" size="60" minlength="3" maxlength="128" required>
      
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">

<button class="submit btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" id="userartifact-submit" onclick="createItem();" value="SUBMIT" style="margin-left:-200px;">Submit</button>

</div>
```

**JS**:

```
function createItem() {
       
     //Fetch the values from the input elements    
    var projectName = $('#txtedit-pname').val();  
    var projectManager = $('#txtedit-pmanager').val();  
    var accountName = $('#txtedit-aname').val();  

   var rei = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('xyz')/items";

    $.ajax({
      async: true
        url: rei,
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.xyzListItem' },
         'nofb': projectName,
         'ug2r': projectManager,
         'nzxf': accountName,      
       }),
  
     headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },

        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log('List Item Created!!');
    }

    function onError(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong jQuery selectors while fetching the values from the input elements.

Use this:

```
// Fetch the values from the input elements    
var projectName = $('input#edit-pname').val();  
var projectManager = $('input#edit-pmanager').val();  
var accountName = $('input#edit-aname').val();
```

OR simply (if element IDs are unique on DOM):

```
// Fetch the values from the input elements    
var projectName = $('#edit-pname').val();  
var projectManager = $('#edit-pmanager').val();  
var accountName = $('#edit-aname').val();
```

---

Also, to create a new item, you don't need `"IF-MATCH": "*"` in `headers`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by removing `IF-MATCH` from the HTTP request header as it makes the request conditional and try it as below:

```
headers: {  
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
          "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
         },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested me but it didn't work.